# Repair ext3 partition on external disk from Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ext3

Currently, what is the best way or tool to repair an `ext3` partition?

There used to be `fsck`, but the disk is an external USB, and using the latest Ubuntu 10.10, I wondered if there might be a new tool that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fsck that works well, go in runlevel 1 :

```
init 1
```

Unmount your usb drive :

```
umount /dev/sda3
```

Run fsck :

```
fsck -t ext3 /dev/sda3
fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

Once fsck finished, remount the file system and go in multiusermode

Answer (score 1):

fsck should still work as the cable medium is inconsequential in this case. I'd be skeptical of any other tool that repairs ext3. It might just be a wrapper for fsck anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The "Disk Utility" in Ubuntu is really nice. You can find it in System, Administration, Disk Utility. It basically shows you a dashboard about all your systems disks. Plug in your external usb, select it from Disk Utilities menu and you will see chapter and verse about your disk. A little green blob indicates the disk is healthy, you can see the SMART status, partitioning info and "Check Filesystem" which I am assuming runs the relevant version of `fsck` per filesystem under the covers.
I recommend using that as if there is something wrong with a drive that's usually a good indicator.